# Creating Google Maps Control that you can drag and drop markers onto map to get their coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, custom-controls

I am creating a GoogleMaps v3 Custom Control that is similar the the little yellow man on google maps. The control has an icon in the top left corner of maps. The user will drag and drop that icon onto the map. Then I just want to get the latlng for that location.

It is not the same as a marker even though it seems like one.

here is what I have so far:

```
var draggableMarkerControl = document.createElement('div');
draggableMarkerControl.setAttribute('class', 'gm-draggable-container'); //h&w of 75px
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push( draggableMarkerControl );
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what to do next? Maybe help find some similar code to work from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question whilst looking for essentially the same thing for my own project. I did find https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/7oWus3T5Ycw which I'm sure could be adapted, but if you look at the source of the example it says the code "is available for a fee".

My approach was going to be to place a temporary marker on the map at a certain position in the window, but then it would have to be recalculated and moved each time the map was moved or zoomed.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the Drawing Library, as suggested on my post by Suvi Vignarajah

[Positioning a draggable map marker at top-left of map window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450051/positioning-a-draggable-map-marker-at-top-left-of-map-window) (there's a jsFiddle in the comments that shows my final solution)

I'm still thinking your idea of a custom control is actually the best in terms of intuitive UX