# Positioning a draggable map marker at top-left of map window

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google map that I am using to allow people to suggest locations. Currently I position a draggable marker in the centre of the map using a LatLng created with

`myPosition = frmMap.getCenter();`

What I would like to do though is place it initially somewhere to the edge of the map, perhaps directly under the zoom control (not unlike the way you see the yellow street view man above the zoom control).

I've searched for a solution but am not coming up with anything. My only idea was to do some maths based on the Center and NortEast but I'd rather have an absolute position based on pixels if that's possible?

Comment: hm..just a side question, did you disable panning & zooming on your map? because the way i see it, even if you position your marker with latlng under the controls, it'd still move if you pan/zoom around in the map..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, computing a `latlng` value for a marker to position under the zoom controls is not only cumbersome, but might not be feasible if the user starts panning/zooming around in the map (as the marker will move wherever the `latlng` takes it).

My suggestion would be to use the [Drawing Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing) provided by the Maps API. This basically gives you a drawing control, to add markers to the map (other overlays are possible too: cirlce, polygon, polyline, rectangle). And like any control google maps provides, you can strictly position them anywhere you'd like - by setting it in the options. The snippet below describes how you initialize the drawing library:

```
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM,
        drawingModes: [
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER
        ]
    }
});

drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

This gives you your drawing control, with the mode for `Marker` enabled, and binds it to your map object.

You can then listen to when a marker's been added by adding a listener on the `drawingManager` variable for the `markercomplete` event. Then in the call back you can get the position of the added marker, the snippet below demonstrates this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'markercomplete', function (marker) {
    var position = marker.getPosition();        
});
```

I put together a small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/J5zMg/) with this example if you'd like to see it in action. Also, click [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManager) for full reference of the Drawing Library for the maps api.

**EDIT:** (start mode in marker add on map load, hide drawing controls after marker added, maker marker draggable)

To start the drawing mode to add marker on map load, simply set the `drawingMode` option in your `drawingManager` variable declaration:

```
`drawingMode : google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER`
```

You can hide the drawing controls in the `markercomplete` event listener:

```
// To hide:
drawingManager.setOptions({
    drawingControl: false //changes UI back to regular map interactions
});
drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); //hides controls
```

Alternatively, if you're never going to need the drawing controls again later in your client interactions you can remove it from the map complete via:

```
drawingManager.setMap(null);
```

Then to make the `marker` draggable, just set the option in the listener as well (because the `marker` in the callback function is a google maps marker object anyway - which references the marker that's added to your map).

```
marker.setOptions({
    draggable: true
});
```

You can then add a listener on the marker object for the `dragend` event to track changes to the location.

Here's in updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/J5zMg/3/

Comment: Thanks Suvi, that's really useful and looks like the way to go. Thanks also for the jsFiddle. 

How easy though do you think it would be to add a behaviour so that as soon as the pin in the drawingManager is clicked the new pin appears directly on the map, and then it is draggable for the user to be able to fine-tune the position? I feel that this is a more intuitive behaviour. I would also like to automatically stop the drawing so that no further pins could be added, and then remove the stop-drawing button completely.

Comment: Sorry, just reading the docs in a bit more depth. I can see I could have it start in drawing mode, but it is not possible, I think, to remove the hand icon. Maybe though it could be coded to switch out of drawing mode as soon as a marker is created?

Comment: Yup, this is definitely possible (minus the hiding the hand icon part). Will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's a nasty hack but this would hide that "hand" icon in your control: `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){ $('div[title="Stop drawing"]').css('visibility', 'hidden'); });`

Comment: Suvi, that's perfect, thank you. In fact I went one further and changed the drawingManager options so that it is not even displayed at all - see http://jsfiddle.net/J5zMg/5/. And to answer your question, once the marker is positioned I don't need the user to use the drawing controls so they can be completely removed at that point (although I guess there's no harm leaving them if they are hidden). The marker position populates lat/lng inputs on a form that allows users to submit locations. Anyway, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Awesome, that works too - as long as it behaves as you expected.